# how do i control width of input with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to control my width's for my input but i am having some trouble. Here is my mark up

```
<section class="bg-lb pt40 pb40 btborder">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="bg-white ">
                    <div class="pt40 pb40">
                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-fade">Login</a>
                        <span id="cricle"><b>OR</b></span>
                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-fade">Register</a>
                    </div>
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="ion-person"></span></div>
                                <input type="text" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="ion-android-lock"></span></div>
                                <input type="password" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="btn btn-default hvr-fade"><b>LOGIN</b></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

im just simply trying to reduce the width of the input and center the form,
live preview here
http://plnkr.co/edit/RN6tPNCynK2lEdTeWmFQ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue using the grid system you can change the way your `col-`'s are setup.

Change:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="bg-white">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="ion-person"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="ion-android-lock"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="bg-white">
    <form>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="ion-person"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="ion-android-lock"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="password" id="" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The main difference is that `<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">` is now specifically wrapping the `<div class="form-group">`. Where the `col-md-offset-3` is what will be centering your form.

Or to go a bit further, create a new `<div class="row">` for each `<div class="form-group">` instead of embedding all columns into one row.

Comment: thank you for helping out Press, I overlooked my grid layout with my form. Thank you again

Comment: @helloworld no problem. However I would suggest using the `offset` class provided by Bootstrap over using two empty `<div>`s. Glad we could help.

Comment: hmm, im not familiar with their offset class, I will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @helloworld it is what I used in my answer to center the inputs. It basically cuts down Mario's answer from using 3 `<div>`s to just one with an added class.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap way is to reduce the width of the column the form is in. With 3 columns you can center the form:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">form comes here</div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DSroqJsfQBTuwBUgo3ps?p=preview

Comment: wow.. you dont know how long I was hacking away changing a bunch of styles to accomplish this. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Just override `bootstrap` `.css` in a particular place. Try this for eg:

put it inside the css:

```
input.form-control{
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

> `input.form-control` will override every `input` with class set to : `form-control`

Or you can shrink the entire `container class`

```
.container{
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

Test here : http://plnkr.co/edit/kR69nCvsDCp9AlQqZztY?p=preview